# Predicting past data from similar series

Tags: time-series, forecasting, predictive-models, prediction

I have a data set that contains the amount sold of a product at each month of 
 2017, for each store that carries it.
Some of the stores only opened in July, so for those I only have 6 months of data. The data set looks like this

```
Store  Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
1      23   25   19   28   19   23   24   18   12   28   33   34
2      -    -    -    -    -    -    14   17   18   19   22   27
3      40   52   21   25   26   45   12   19   15   22   27   26
```

I would like to estimate how much those stores would have sold in the first 6 months of the year, but I'm not really sure how to do it.

I thought about adjusting a time series model, including the sales of the other stores as variables to capture tendencies, but I don't know if that makes sense theory-wise.

Can I do that? Is there another method that would make more sense in this scenario?

PS: The data above is only to illustrate the problem. I actually have a lot more stores and a bigger time frame with more disperse data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whereas I like your idea of using data from other stores ...It is clear that stores 1 & 3 are dissimilar. I have found that if you reverse your data you can predict earlier values. For example [image] leads to this model [image] with this as the actual/fit/forecast [image] . Specifically the forecasts for the first 6 months would be [image]

Comment: What is your basis for asserting stores 1 and 3 are "dissimilar" and in what way do you think they differ? There really aren't enough data either to relate the store sales to each other or even to find significant trends over time. The backcasts depend entirely on the three unusually high sales in Store 3 in January, February and June, but since Store 1 did not experience such spikes, relying on them to analyze Store 2 looks foolhardy.

Comment: I didn't suggest using the store 1 and 3 to reverse predict store 2 ...I simply said it "could make sense" but the data for store 1 and 3 seemed dissimilar to me as store 3 had very high sales in Jan and Feb ( probably outliers ) where store 1's values seemed more stable thus one would get widely different forecasts for period 1-6 using either store 1 or store 3 as the basis.,

Comment: ...................

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The data I provided above is fictional. I included it just to illustrate the problem as I'm not allowed to share the real thing. In the actual data I can find similar stores that have very similar tendencies, so I'll to use your approach.

Comment: OK ... uptick my answer and close the question and feel free to contact me offline if you have any issues ...